# Can you get more specific exception or cause of getting PersistenceException when calling createEntityManager while using OpenJPA

Tags: java, jpa, exception, derby, openjpa

While connecting to Derby database using OpenJPA, i have encountered this PersistenceException, which says connection could not be obtained for Derby EmbeddedDriver driver class, **but that is not important** (i know how to fix it):

```
77  RegistryManagement  INFO   [JavaFX Application Thread] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjp
a.jdbc.sql.DerbyDictionary".
<openjpa-3.1.2-r66d2a72 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There were errors i
nitializing your configuration: <openjpa-3.1.2-r66d2a72 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: A conne
ction could not be obtained for driver class "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" and URL "jdbc:derby:db".  You may ha
ve specified an invalid URL.
....
```

Important is that there is this Caused by in that exception:

```
....
Caused by: ERROR XJ004: XJ004.C : [0] db
    at 
....
```

which is one of Derby error codes (https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/ref/rrefexcept71493.html).

This `PersistenceException` was thrown when calling `.createEntityManager()`. Is it pretty long when it comes to text length.

I can catch that `PersistenceException` by wrapping `.createEntityManager()` with try-catch, but i can not figure out how to find more information about what is the cause, aka. get the error code, because `PersistenceException` can be thrown for various reasons. And i can not wrap it with catching `SQLException` or `UserException`, because my IDE says that method does not throw these exceptions.

I tried calling `.getMessage()` or `.getCause()` on that `PersistenceException`, but i got almost same long text.

When i called `.getCause()` it returns `RuntimeException` and I could see this, that Derby thrown `SQLException`:

```
....
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: XJ004.C : [0] db
    at 
....
```

calling `.getCause()` again returns null.

I do not want to search the whole message (String) for occurences of some error codes, because that might be resource heavy. I think this problem might not be specific to Derby and happen while using other sql dbs, which might also throw some exception.

My code:

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
    private EntityManagerFactory managerFactory;
    private EntityManager manager;

    public DatabaseManager(String persistenceUnitName, Map<String, String> properties)
    {
        managerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, properties);
        try
        {
            manager = managerFactory.createEntityManager();
        }
        catch(PersistenceException e)
        {
            //stuff
        }
    }
....
```

EntityManagerFactory is an interface from javax.persistence package:

```
public interface EntityManagerFactory {

    public EntityManager createEntityManager();
....
```

Comment: Please show us your code which is responsible for handling this error and also the code which might be responsible for throwing this error.

Comment: @paladin I do not think that will help, but i did it

Comment: Read about the api specification of PersistenceException -> https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html try to catch all subclass exceptions (EntityExistsException, EntityNotFoundException, LockTimeoutException, NonUniqueResultException, NoResultException, OptimisticLockException, PessimisticLockException, QueryTimeoutException, RollbackException, TransactionRequiredException) before you try to catch the PersistenceException. This should give you a more detailed error handling.

Comment: @paladin Tried to catch all of them, but its not any of these subclasses. As you can see in first code in question - PersistenceException is thrown, because of org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException, which is thrown because of SQLException from Derby.

Comment: You can try this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was debugging, found this methods in `PersistenceExceptions` class, which are
from OpenJPA:

```
@Override
public RuntimeException translate(RuntimeException re) {
    return PersistenceExceptions.toPersistenceException(re);
}
```

this method translates caught `RuntimeException`, which is in question's case OpenJPA's `UserException` caused by `SQLException`, and then creates new `PersistenceException` based on it here and returns it:

```
/**
 * Translate the given general exception.
 */
private static Throwable translateGeneralException(OpenJPAException ke) {
   Exception e = new org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException
        (ke.getMessage(), getNestedThrowables(ke),
            getFailedObject(ke), ke.isFatal());
    e.setStackTrace(ke.getStackTrace());
    return e;
}
```

As you can see creating new org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException based on `OpenJPAException` values (and not itself) causes that it is not possible to retrieve lower cause.

OpenJPA version 3.1.2